# JS: Filter and get an object from a nested Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a record of "12345", Now I want to get the list of all the items and it's keys which have the same ID as the record.

This is what the object looks like:

```
const data = [
{
        "key": "6180571060967405762c1fc2",
        "code": [
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "12345"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "sdaasdasdas"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "sdadsadasdasdas"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "6180571160967405762c1fc3",
        "code": [
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "dsadasddd"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "dasdasass"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "dsfsdasdf"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "sdfsdasdf"
            }
          },
          {
            "other": {
              "id": "fdsafsdaf"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

]

expected output: An array of keys of the object which contains a record of 12345

```
[6180571060967405762c1fc2, xxxx, xxxxx, all the objects that have my record in it's nested elements.]
```

UPDATE:

I have just realized sometime there are objects which do not return the nested objects at all, and my array may look like this: (no code object)

```
    const data = [
    {
            "key": "6180571060967405762c1fc2",
            "code": [
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "12345"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "sdaasdasdas"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "sdadsadasdasdas"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "6180571160967405762c1fc3",
            "code": [
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "dsadasddd"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "dasdasass"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "dsfsdasdf"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "sdfsdasdf"
                }
              },
              {
                "other": {
                  "id": "fdsafsdaf"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
 {
            "key": "6423534534405762c1fc3",
          },

]
```

Comment: `data.filter(x => x.code.some(y => y.id === '12345')).map(x => x.key)`

Comment: Awesome thank you! I am gonna try and see if it works now :)

Comment: About your update: then make it  `x.code?.some` with question mark.